# LinearGradient above ImageBackground in react-native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, linear-gradients, imagebackground

In my react-native expo app, i have a background image that is taking full height and width in all screens and i want to put a lineargradient above the background image but it's not working, the image is always appearing above the gradient, here is the code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { LinearGradeint } from 'expo';
    import { Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

    class App extends Component {

      render() {

        return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <LinearGradient
          colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('./images/background.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
            <View style={{width: "100%"}}>
            <Text>
              HI
            </Text>
          </View>
           </ImageBackground>
          </LinearGradient>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        flex: 1,
      },
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to put LinearGradient component inside ImageBackground.

```
<ImageBackground source={require('./images/background.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
     <LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} />
          <View style={{width: "100%"}}>
          </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<ImageBackground
  source={require('../../assets/img/background.png')}
  resizeMode="cover"
  style={{
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    flex: 1,
  }}>
  <LinearGradient
    colors={[
      'rgba(255,180,113,0.75)',
      'rgba(255,107,11,0.75)',
      'rgba(255,180,113,0.75)',
    ]}
    style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>

    {** CODE **}

  </LinearGradient>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Please provide additional information for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Add absolute position on the LinearGradient :

```
<LinearGradient
   colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
   style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      height: '100%'
   }}
/>
```